# document addEventListener touchstart does not have any response in Safari console

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, touch-event

I'm trying to debug my code. Below code can "console.log" message when touch in Chrome, but no any message printed out in Safari. Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
            text = target.textContent || target.innerText;   
            console.log(target, text);
            }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this iOS Safari or macOS Safari?

Comment: both. iOS Safari or macOS Safari

Answer (score 0):

Currently, dekstop Safari does not support touch API.

You can see compatibility table [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) or by using [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=touch)

Comment: any suggestions for alternative?

Comment: @PakHoCheung you could try to use some polyfill. Safari supports PointerEvents, so you should look for polyfill that takes use of  that.